# Multilevel web spider with regex match?

Tags: regex, web-scraping, web-crawler

I need a web spider to find certain links with regex.

The spider would visit a list of websites, find links that match a regex pattern list, visit those matched links and repeat until the configured depth level.

I was about to code this on php but im not very good with threads on php and I need threads for this application.

So, what do you think is the best solution?

Maybe theres some existing app/code I could configure to create this spider.

Comment: Is your goal to discover links? If so, I would recommend that you don't specify a depth... there are other more efficient ways to ensure that the crawler finds enough links without being stuck on a certain path. What's your goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several crawlers out there which you can use for free:

- [Nutch](http://nutch.apache.org/)
- [Heritrix](http://crawler.archive.org/)
- [Wikipedia list of open-source crawlers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler#Open-source_crawlers)

Nutch is probably the best and I would recommend that if you use it, you take advantage of their OPIC functionality instead of specifying the crawl depth yourself. OPIC allows the crawler to determine which site should be crawled next in an intelligent way, without the need of artificial depth limits.